# How to customize a UIDatePicker in countdown mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidatepicker

I want to customize the minimum time the user can pick on a UIDatePicker in countdown mode. I want it to only allow a minimum interval of 30min but the picker always displays 0 and then the subsequent intervals. If I set a 5min interval, is there any way to have the picker show {30min, 35min, 40min, ... } ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
myDatePicker.minuteInterval = 5;
myDatePicket.countDownDuration = 180;
```